# transitions no actualiza modelo en vista

Tags: angularjs

Estimados, estoy utilizando `$transitions` para identificar desde que `$state` se esta llegando a uno determinado.

```
$transitions.onSuccess({ from: 'trabajos/nuevo_trabajo' }, (trans) => {
    cargarDatos();
});

var cargarDatos = function(){
    nuevoVehiculo = angular.fromJson(SessionFactory.getDataByKey('nuevoVehiculo'));
    if (nuevoVehiculo) {
        $scope.data.nombre_cliente = nuevoVehiculo.nombre_cliente;
        $scope.data.patente = nuevoVehiculo.patente;
        $scope.data.anio = nuevoVehiculo.anio;
        $scope.data.kilometros = nuevoVehiculo.kilometros;
        $scope.data.marca = nuevoVehiculo.marca;
        $scope.data.modelo = nuevoVehiculo.modelo;
        $scope.data.cilindrada = nuevoVehiculo.cilindrada;
        $scope.data.telefono = nuevoVehiculo.telefono_cliente;
    }
    console.log($scope.data);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="nuevoVehiculoForm" data-ng-submit="nuevoVehiculo()">
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Patente</label>
            <input required name="patente" ng-model="data.patente" ng-pattern="/^((([a-z]|[A-Z]){2}[0-9]{4})|(([a-z]|[A-Z]){4}[0-9]{2}))$/" maxlength="6">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.patente.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Patente es obligatoria.</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Patente inválida.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Año</label>
            <input required name="anio" ng-model="data.anio" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.anio.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar un Año.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>KM</label>
            <input required name="kilometros" ng-model="data.kilometros" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.kilometros.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar un Kilometraje.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Marca</label>
            <input required name="marca" ng-model="data.marca">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.marca.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Marca.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Modelo</label>
            <input required name="modelo" ng-model="data.modelo" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.modelo.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Modelo.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Cilindrada</label>
            <input required name="cilindrada" ng-model="data.cilindrada" type="number">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.cilindrada.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Debe ingresar Cilindrada</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div layout layout-sm="column">
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Nombre completo</label>
            <input type="text" required name="nombre_cliente" ng-model="data.nombre_cliente" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></input>
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.nombre_cliente.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Nombre completo es obligatorio.</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex class="input-form-custom">
            <label>Telefono</label>
            <input ng-pattern="/^([0-9]*)?$/" minlength="11" maxlength="11" required name="telefono" ng-model="data.telefono" type="text">
            <div ng-messages="nuevoVehiculoForm.telefono.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Teléfono es obligatorio</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres.</div>
                <div ng-message="maxlength">Teléfono debe tener 11 caracteres.</div>
                <div ng-message="pattern">Teléfono debe ser numérico</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <center>
        <button ng-disabled="!canSubmit()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ingresarNuevoVehiculo()">Ingresar</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

La impresión de `$scope.data` me refleja los cambios y actualiza el modelo. Sin embargo, en el codigo HTML no se ve reflejado el cambio. No se porque no se actualiza.

**EDICION**

Logre hacer funcionar el `stateChangeSuccess` pero aun asi, el modelo no se actualiza. Me parece que el problema no pasa por eso, agregue codigo html.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs@1.0.0/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/stateEvents.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hay forma de que puedas mostrar un ejemplo reproduciendo el error?

Comment: Intentare hacer un codePen y te comento!

Comment: Agrega el html para confirmar que esta utilizando en el modelo correcto en tu  vista

Comment: @Einer agregue el html!

Answer (score 0):

Hay distintas posibles causas como:

- La llamada asíncrona no se termina a tiempo para renderizarse.
- El ciclo de `$digest` está en destiempo.

Puedes probar alguna de las siguientes alternativas:

1. ```
   $transitions.onSuccess({ from: 'trabajos/nuevo_trabajo' }, (trans)=>
   {
       $timeout(cargarDatos());
   });
   ```
2. ```
   $transitions.onSuccess({ from: 'trabajos/nuevo_trabajo' }, (trans)=> 
   {
       cargarDatos(); 
       $digest();
   });
   ```
3. Revisar que no esté usando *one time bind*.

   ```
   {{ ::vm.data.nombre}}
   ```

Comment: Hola!, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lamentablemente ninguna de las opciones me funciono... en el punto 3 a que te refieres? yo utilizo los modelos en el html asi : `<input required name="anio" ng-model="data.anio" type="number">`

Comment: la opción de _one time binding_ se usa para que los objetos o variables que se especifiquen en la sintaxis mencionada dejen de ser incluidos en el ciclo de $digest una vez que estos tengan un valor valido por primera vez. https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/

Comment: la verdad no lo utilizo... no se porque no se carga la data.. me esta rompiendo la cabeza este problema!!

Comment: ya intentaste crear un servicio para acceder a la información desde fuera de ese controller? Y por cierto, si lo que necesitas es tener información sobre el estado anterior, te recomiendo que lo pongas en el $rootScope y no en el $scope del controller de el $state

Comment: el `SessionFactory` guarda información en el localStorage, mi idea principal es que si se viene de trabajos/nuevo_trabajo, recupere la información, de lo contrario que deje el formulario vacio.

Comment: Pude activar el stateChangeSuccess pero tampoco se actualizan los modelos, no se que problema puede ser....

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la funcion donde realizas los cambios no pertenece al `$scope` y por tanto, no se actualiza de forma automática. Para que lo haga, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var cargarDatos = function(){
    nuevoVehiculo = angular.fromJson(SessionFactory.getDataByKey('nuevoVehiculo'));
    if (nuevoVehiculo) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.data.nombre_cliente = nuevoVehiculo.nombre_cliente;
            $scope.data.patente = nuevoVehiculo.patente;
            $scope.data.anio = nuevoVehiculo.anio;
            $scope.data.kilometros = nuevoVehiculo.kilometros;
            $scope.data.marca = nuevoVehiculo.marca;
            $scope.data.modelo = nuevoVehiculo.modelo;
            $scope.data.cilindrada = nuevoVehiculo.cilindrada;
            $scope.data.telefono = nuevoVehiculo.telefono_cliente;
            console.log($scope.data);
        });
    }
}
```

Con eso consigues que `data` sea forzada a VER que se hizo una actualización y actuar entonces en base a eso. Saludos.

Comment: Hola!, gracias por tu respuesta.. pense eso tambien pero aplique el `$apply` y tampoco funciono